# Find center of a circle

Tags: c#, trigonometry

I need some c# code for the following:

I have two points (2D). The points are on a circle with radius r. I know the tangent angle in each of the points. I need to get hold of the circle mid point.

//Thomas

---

OK, I think I was a bit unclear. See image below. The point P1 is at the end of a line, the line has the angle At1. The point P2 is at the beginning of a line with the angle At2. I know the coordinates for P1 and P2. I also know the angles At1 and At2. A radius is formed between P1 and P2 and I need to know the center point Pc for the (invisible) circle the which is formed with P1, P2, At1 and At2. The points P1 and P2 can be anywhere in the coordiante system.

I know it's not c#, however I was hoping to come across someone who's solved this.

[See image](http://thomashellstrom.com/centerpoint.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "tangent angle"?

Comment: If this is homework, please mark it as such.

Comment: are you looking for r or the midpoint? do you have either r or the midpoint also? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equation

Comment: If the points are not known to be most-far from one another on the circle, then there is an infinite amount of circles that they can be on.

Comment: if you dont have midpoint or r you will need atleast 3 points on a circle to determine its radius or it has infinite posibilities. as its not known whether or not these points are directly opposite eachother or what, though with a known angle between them, it would half the number of infinite posibilities i guess...

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "tangent angle"!

Comment: I'm guessing he means he knows the angle of tangent line at each point which means you can draw two rays perpendicular to the tangent from each point, find their intersection and bob's-your-uncle there's your centre point.  EDIT: maybe I'm wrong though 'cause then you don't need radius.

Comment: Also, another comment on my solution is that if the two tangents are parallel, then you would have to use the solution provided by Yorye Nathan.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I don't thing that's what he meant by "tangent angle". I think he's just mixing things up. I can't see how he would have a tangent of an angle between a dot and some void. Angles between the line the dots create and the axis obviously aren't related, so... OP clarify please?

Answer (score 1):

If the points are not known to be most-far from one another on the circle, then there is an infinite amount of circles that they can be on.

Otherwise, it's simple:

```
Point pt1 = ...
Point pt2 = ...

Point mid = new Point((pt1.X + pt2.X) / 2, (pt1.Y + pt2.Y) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the tangent angles are parallel.  If they are, then all you need to do is find the midpoint between them (as they both lay along the circle's diameter) as per Yorye Nathan's solution.

If they're not parallel, then you can draw two lines perpendicular to the tangent angles starting from your known P1 and P2.  If you solve the intersection of these two lines, then that intersection will be Pc.

I don't have the time right now to write up the full C# math and test it, but some pseudocode for you might be:

```
public Point CalculateCircleCentre(Point p1, Degrees tangent1, Point p2, Degrees tangent2)
{
    if (AreAnglesParallel(tangent1, tangent2))
    {
        return Midpoint(p1, p2);
    }
    else
    {
        var line1 = new Line(p1, tangent1 + 90);
        var line2 = new Line(p2, tangent2 + 90);
        var intersectionPoint = FindIntersection(line1, line2);

        return intersectionPoint;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have 2 points on a circle with coordinates (x1, y1), (x2, y2) and point (x3, y3) is the center of a circle with radius r all you need to do is to find x3 and y3. Solve this system:

```
(x3-x1)^2+(y3-y1)^2=r^2
(x3-x2)^2+(y3-y2)^2=r^2
```

expands to

```
 x3*x3-2*x3*x1+x1*x1 + y3*y3-2*y3*y1+y1*y1 = r*r

 x3*x3-2*x3*x2+x2*x2 + y3*y3-2*y3*y2+y2*y2 = r*r

2*x3*(x2-x1) + 2*y3*(y2-y1) + x1*x1 + x2*x2 + y1*y1 + y2*y2 = 0
```

You now can substitute x3 with this long expression and find y3

```
x3 = (2*y3*(y1-y2) - (x1*x1 + x2*x2 + y1*y1 + y2*y2)) / (2*(x2-x1))
```

After that you will know everything to find x3.